# How to quickly re-group/pivot data with CUDA C?

Tags: cuda, pivot, grouping, simulation, gpgpu

In an SIR infection simulation, a person can either be susceptible to (S), infected by (I) or recovered from (R) a disease. From time `t` to `t+1`, the infection status of person `i` from population `P` might develop as follows (left-hand table):

[image: Persons 2 and 9 become infected, while person 6 recovers.]

(*Here, persons 2 and 9 become infected, while person 6 recovers. Note the status of a person can only develop in one direction from S → I → R.*)

Now, I also want to *group* people by their status like in the right-hand table, much like an Excel PivotTable. I will need updated groupings after each time period in the simulation, and ideally each 'grouping array' is sorted (lists people in ascending order by index `i`).

As such, how can I recalculate/update these 3 grouping arrays in the fastest manner at each time period? (I have considered using atomic operations, but have been advised to avoid atomic operations as much as possible due to being slow.)

The simulation will be implemented in CUDA C, with each thread mapping onto each person within population `P`.

Many thanks.

Comment: Would a single sorted vector with the starting points of each group be  an acceptable solution ?

Comment: Could you clarify by giving an example of what you mean with respect to the above? Thanks

Comment: In your example, t would be `1 2 7 9 10 3 5 6 4 8` followed by another vector with `1 6 9` as starting locations of S, I, R. t+1 would have `1 7 10 2 3 5 9 4 6 8`, followed by another vector with `1 4 8` as starting locations. If required, we can have a mapping function from t to t+1 as `1 4 2 7 3 5 6 9 8 10`

Comment: Yes, @Pavan. That would be an informationally equivalent and hence acceptable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
__global__
static void find_groups(int *locs, int *sorted, int num)
{
    int bid = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int tid = bid * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < num) {
        int curr = sorted[tid];
        if (tid == 0 || curr != sorted[tid - 1]) locs[curr] = tid;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int h_P0[N] = {0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0};
    int h_P1[N] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0};

    thrust::host_vector<int> th_P0(h_P0, h_P0 + N);
    thrust::host_vector<int> th_P1(h_P1, h_P1 + N);

    thrust::device_vector<int> td_P0 = th_P0;
    thrust::device_vector<int> td_P1 = th_P1;

    thrust::device_vector<int> td_S0(N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> td_S1(N);

    thrust::sequence(td_S0.begin(), td_S0.end());
    thrust::sequence(td_S1.begin(), td_S1.end());

    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(td_P0.begin(), td_P0.end(), td_S0.begin());
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(td_P1.begin(), td_P1.end(), td_S1.begin());

    thrust::device_vector<int> td_l0(3, -1); // Changed here
    thrust::device_vector<int> td_l1(3, -1); // And here

    int threads =  256;
    int blocks_x = (N + 256) / 256;
    int blocks_y = (blocks_x + 65535) / 65535;
    dim3 blocks(blocks_x, blocks_y);

    int *d_l0 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(td_l0.data());
    int *d_l1 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(td_l1.data());
    int *d_P0 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(td_P0.data());
    int *d_P1 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(td_P1.data());

    find_groups<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_l0, d_P0, N);
    find_groups<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_l1, d_P1, N);

    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm can be explained in simple steps.

- Sort P0 by key
- Sort P1 by key
- The keys now contain the second table

Now pass P0 and P1 to find_groups kernel. Since you know there are only 3 groups, the thread where the group number changes from n-1 to n writes to global memory. thread 0 will always write 0, because that is the beginning of first group for all vectors.

I tried printing them out. This is what I get. Please keep in mind everything is 0 indexed.

```
Sorted
t    t+1
0    0
1    6
6    9
8    1
9    2
2    4
4    8
5    3
3    5
7    7
Ranges
Groups   t   t + 1
S    [0-4]   [0-2]
I    [5-7]   [3-6]
R    [8-9]   [7-9]
```

If you need access to the full code (including the code for printing), visit [this link](https://gist.github.com/4508156).

I am not sure if this is enough. But do let me know if I missed something here.

*EDIT*

Changed code to handle where a class is missing. Initialize the relevant vectors with -1. So when you encounter a starting point of -1, it would mean the class doesn't show up in that iteration.

Comment: Much appreciated. But what if `P0` and `P1` reside on the device to begin with? How to get thrust to operate on vectors that reside on the GPU?

Comment: @MiloChen If you have the vectors already on the gpu, use `thrust::device_vector<int>(d_ptr, d_ptr + N)`

Comment: Thanks - also, how do I pass a device vector to another function or give it global scope?

Comment: You can use raw_pointer_cast and get the device vector out and use it like a regular device vector once the processing is done.

Comment: Sure, but if I use `raw_pointer_cast` to get the raw device vector out and proceed make changes to the raw device vector, can I still continue to use the old thrust device vector container or will the two become 'out of sync'?

Comment: @MiloChen I am not 100% certain, but I am *pretty sure* that you can update raw pointer and still have the thrust device vector. However I am not certain what will happen if device_vector goes out of scope, but you decide to pass raw pointer outside.

Comment: After debugging the code for a while, I noticed the following flaw: what if an entire class of status is missing at a particular iteration, e.g. there is only `S` or `R` at some stage (say, `h_P1[N] = {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0};`). Then `d_l1 = {S_begin, I_begin, R_begin} = {0, 0, 7}`) will contain missing values (`I_begin`) that need to be filled somehow (to get the desired vector `{0, 7, 7}`) - any ideas?

Comment: @MiloChen Sorry for missing that. I will look into sorting this out.

Comment: @MiloChen it only requires two small edits. The starting point shows up as -1 now if it does not exist in the current iteration.